# Firefox, display issues on a input form HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, firefox

I don't know why but on firefox when I type in a input the text is hidden (but when I click out of the input the text is display), on google chrome it works well, I try to change the z-index but it doesn't change anything.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="searchBar" class="{% if query %}cancelable{% endif %}">
    <input class="searchInput" type="text" autocomplete="off"
        value="{{ query|default_if_none('')|escape }}"
        name="query" id="keywords"/>
    <input type="submit" value="" name="search" class="searchBtn" style="display: none;"/>
</div>
```

This is my CSS

```
#searchBar input.searchInput {
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 22px;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    font-weight: 300;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 0px;
    color: #484848;
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 8px 0 6px 0;
    padding: 0 80px 0 8px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #929292;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 #929292;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 #929292;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

#searchBar input.searchInput:focus {
    margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
    padding: 20px 40px 18px 8px;
    border: solid 1px rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(82, 168, 236, 0.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -moz-transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -o-transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow
}
```

PS : #searchBar has a z-index of 1000 I try to switch it to 10 it still has the same behavior on firefox.

Comment: please create a fiddle and the other one is why you give `padding` on focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've large amount of `padding` which is causing the issue and moreover you are using `height` of `26px` and hence the text hides

```
padding: 20px 40px 18px 8px;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pf4nF/)

You can remove the red border later(I've kept for test purposes)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pf4nF/1/)

Few tips on refactoring code

- This margin: `0px 0 0px 0;` can be simply written as `margin: 0;`
- No need of any shadow in your code as they are set to `0`
- `z-index` is not required
- `line-height` is not required(If you aren't using any fixed height)
- `top`, `left` not required

Comment: Thank you, I have to increase the height of my input and decrease the padding ? Your fiddle's demos aren't loading on my computer :/

Comment: @NicolasHENAUX Remove height, remove padding